# Access Violation in call stack

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, pointers, access-violation

I get this error: First-chance exception at 0x003f31b5 in Cts.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xe1672514.

When I use the call stack, it spits out to this method. 
I commented which line specifically.

When I click cancel from debugging when the program runs, the violation happens.

At the bottom, I have included my Cancel method as well.

```
void CInpINS::OnTimer(UINT nIDEvent) 
{

  int i,j, totalbytes;
  bool bfilefnd = false;


  CConvb Convb;
  CString tmp;

  for (i = 0; i < (int) m_nNumMsgs; i++) {
      m_pBDF[i]->m_numrecs = m_pIDF[i]->m_numrecs;

      for (j = 0; j < MAXBYTECNT; j++) {
                OutBytes[j] = 0;
      }

        // set first 5 words 
      OutBytes[1] = m_nSelectedMsgNum[i];

      OutBytes[3] = (int)m_pIDF[i]->IDFFields[m_pIDF[i]->m_numrecs-1].ebyte/2+6; // THIS LINE SPECIFICALLY

      CConvb Convb;

      if (i == 0) m_dTimeofTransmission += m_nRate;
      tmp.Format("%20.0f",m_dTimeofTransmission);

      Convb.CONV_Timetag_to_Bytes(tmp, OutBytes[4], OutBytes[5],
                              OutBytes[6], OutBytes[7],
                              OutBytes[8], OutBytes[9],
                              OutBytes[10], OutBytes[11]);

        // start at 11 because byte 0 and 1 are input or output msg, then bytes 2 and 3 are word count
        // bytes 4 through 11 are gps time
        for (j = 0; j < m_pBDF[i]->m_numrecs; j++) {
            if ((j == 0)||(j == 1))  
            {
                Convb.ConvFld(tmp,
                    m_pIDF[i]->IDFFields[j].bbyte+9,
                    m_pIDF[i]->IDFFields[j].ebyte+9,
                    m_pIDF[i]->IDFFields[j].bbit,
                    m_pIDF[i]->IDFFields[j].ebit,
                    m_pIDF[i]->IDFFields[j].dtype,
                    m_pIDF[i]->IDFFields[j].Desc,OutBytes);

            }
            else
            {
                Convb.ConvFld(m_pBDF[i]->BDFFields[j],
                    m_pIDF[i]->IDFFields[j].bbyte+9,
                    m_pIDF[i]->IDFFields[j].ebyte+9,
                    m_pIDF[i]->IDFFields[j].bbit,
                    m_pIDF[i]->IDFFields[j].ebit,
                    m_pIDF[i]->IDFFields[j].dtype,
                    m_pIDF[i]->IDFFields[j].Desc,OutBytes);

            }
        }

        totalbytes = OutBytes[3];
        m_pDoc->sendmsg(totalbytes, false, OutBytes);
        tmp.Format("Sent Message");
        AddToListBox(tmp);
        UpdateData(false);
        m_nNumSent +=1;

}

}
```

Here is the cancel method:

```
void CInpINS::OnCancel() 
    {
if (m_bSetIDF) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < (int) m_nNumMsgs; i++) {
        delete m_pIDF[i];
        delete m_pIDFCustm[i];
        delete m_pBDF[i];   
    }
    m_bSetIDF = false;
}

AfxGetMainWnd()->PostMessage(WM_GOODBYEINPINS, IDOK);

CDialog::OnCancel();

}
```

This is coded in C++ Visual Studio 2010. I think there may be some NULL pointers or something but I am not sure. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe `m_pIDF[i]->m_numrecs-1` is out of bounds for your `IDFFields` array. Look at your variables when it breaks into the debugger.

Comment: Many things could be happening here. `this` could be invalid. `i` or `m_pIDF[i]->m_numrecs-1` could be out of range. The pointer at `m_pIDF[i]` could be dangling or uninitialized. Gremlins elsewhere in the program could have smashed the stack. I think we'll need a [mcve] to help sort this one out.

Comment: @drescherjm But wouldn't that give me a different error other than an access violation?

Comment: ***But wouldn't that give me a different error other than an access violation?*** Since `c++` has no requirement to check bounds not necessarily.

Comment: Are you stopping the timer (and making sure the TimerProc has exited) before pulling the proverbial rug out from underneath it by `delete`ing the memory?

Comment: @PhilM I am adding on to code that has been written before me so I am not sure whether or not that has happened. The entire file consists of thousands of lines of code that is why I can't post everything. Where do you suggest I take a look at?

Comment: Look at the variables after the crash broke into the debugger. That should tell you if @PhilM or my guesses are correct. Is `this` valid? Can you look at the local variables? Is  `m_pIDF[i]->m_numrecs-1` out of bounds?

Comment: @drescherjm There is no `this` operator.

Comment: Your code is probably creating the Timer somewhere with `SetTimer`, and hopefully storing the ID returned. You need to pass that to `KillTimer` to stop the timer, before you start deleting memory. Then you'll want some method of making sure `OnTimer` has exited before the actual `delete`s.

Comment: @PhilM Wow...you're a genius! Thank you so much this solved my issue! If you want to add your comment as a solution I will mark it!

Comment: ***There is no this operator*** Of course. I mean the `this` pointer as seen in the debugger. If you look at the `Locals` tab in `Visual Stuido` when debugging the `this` pointer is the first item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `OnCancel` is de-allocating memory without making sure that `OnTimer` isn't still accessing that memory.

Make sure to call `KillTimer` (and ensure that `OnTimer` has finished) before deleting the variables.